# Custom TableView and using didSelectRowAtIndexPath in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I have created a custom TableView by following this [Custom UITableViewCell](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_kO-J3DYvc)

I creared a CustomerCell and then use it like this in ViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = @"cutomerCell";

    CustomerCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (CustomerCell *) [self.tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:uniqueIdentifier];

    Customer *customer = [self.customers objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    if(!cell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomerCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObject)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomerCell class]])
            {
                cell = (CustomerCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cell.nameLabel.text = customer.name;

    return cell;
}
```

Everything works fine. But then I start the next link [UINavigationController](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XN4JRic6TM8)

The problem is when I use this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@ "hi");   
}
```

When I click on an item in TableView, nothing happen. It could be because of I implement the `Custom TableView` and then I can't use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, but how can I fix it?

Comment: Is your NSLog printing "hi" in your console?

Comment: Yes take delegate, that will make it work..

Comment: sorry I'm a beginner in iOS, how can I take the delegate? I used `tableView.delegate = self;` but does not work. where should I use it?

Comment: Yes this is the right way... also have you taken <UITableViewDataSource, UiTableViewDelegate > in your .h file?

Comment: Yes exactly I have <UITableViewDataSource, UiTableViewDelegate >

Comment: and have you set tableView.datasource=self?You should use it in viewDidLoad

Comment: I got error on this line : `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14621/discussion-between-ali-and-iphone-developer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is related to your nib and not your UITableView. You should check if the view of Customer Detail class is connected to its owner in the nib. That is why it crashes as soon as you try to use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.customerDetail animated:YES];
```

Comment: Now I solved the problem : `Connect the view to its Owner`, I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the delegate?
tableView.delegate = self; and you should be fine, I guess.

Comment: yeah, when you initialize your TableView. If you use the Interface Builder, you can connect the tableView Delegate directly with your ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing the table view should not cause such a problem -- a subclass, by definition, does everyting plus something more than that of its superclass. It seems that you have only set the data source but the delegate:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used the code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. but does not work. I used it in `viewDidLoad` doesn't wrok. can you help me where should I use it?

Comment: In didSelectRowAtIndexPath it naturally doesn't work (think it about for a moment, it's obvious why not). In viewDidLoad, make sure you set the delegate AFTER you create the table view. Setting a delegate of nil has no effect (why? Read the Obj-C runtime docs.)